# Designing an OOP solution

Tags: python, oop

Im writing code for research purposes, in which I search through a bulk of files and rank them according to their relevance. I call the entire process quickSearching, and it is composed of two serial stages - first I search the file and retrieve a list a candidates files, then I score those candidates and rank them.

So a quicksearch is simply a serial combination of a search method and a score method.
Im planning to implement various searching and scoring methodologies, and I would like to test all possible combinations and evaluate them to see which is the winning combo.

Since the number of combos will grow very fast, It is important to write the code in a good structure and design. I thought about the following designs (Im writing the code in python):

1. A quickSearcher class that will receive pointers to a searcher and scorer functions
2. A quickSearcher class that will receive a searcher object and a scorer object
3. A quickSearcher calss that will inherit from a searcher class and an scorer class

since Im basically an EE engineer, Im not sure how to select between the options and if this a common problem in CS with trivial pattern design.The design i'm looking will hopefully:

1. Be very code-volume efficient, since some of the searching and scoring methods differ in simply a different value of a parameter or two.
2. Be very modular and logical errors prone.
3. Be easy to navigate through
4. Any other consideration I should take?

This is my first design question so it might not be valid or missing important info, please notify me if it is.

Comment: Does your scoring methods just assigns score to one file according to just its own information, or doing some more complicated work with more than one files?

Comment: It works on one file, but it does do complicated work which is broken down to several auxiliary functions. It is not simple enough to fit in when score() func. the same goes for the search methods.

Comment: Search engines are no walk in the park. Any reason you want to write one by yourself when there already are free open-source working solutions?

Comment: What Im working on is quite unique :) (or so I hope)

Answer (score 1):

Classes are often overused, especially by programmers coming from languages like Java and C# where they are compulsory.  I recommend watching the presentation [Stop Writing Classes](http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes).

When deciding whether to create a class it is useful to ask yourself the following questions:

1) Will the class need to have multiple methods?

If the class only has a single method (apart from `__init__`) then you may as well make it a function instead.  If it needs to preserve state between calls then use a generator.  If it needs to be created in one place with some parameters then called elsewhere you can use a closure (a function that returns another function) or `functools.partial`.

2) will it need to share state between methods?

If the class does not need to share state between methods then it may be better replaced with either a set of independent functions or smaller classes (or some combination).

If the answer to both questions is yes then go ahead and create a class.

For your example I think option 1 is the way to go.  The searcher and scorer objects sound like they if they are classes they will only have a single method, probably called something like `execute` or `run`.  Make them functions instead.

Depending on your use case, quickSorter itself may be better off as a function or generator as well, so no need for any classes at all.

BTW there is no distinction in Python between a function and a pointer to a function.

Comment: if by "preserve state" between to calls you mean that the function needs it's local vars the same between calls, then no, it doesnt. the searcher and the scorer methods each have 4-5 aux methods because they both use a lot of info collected offline, so it is not only run(). Regarding state sharing, then yes, I would like to initialize the environment once (loading a whole bunch of info and statistics) and then evaluate different score & search combo's on it. the state itself will not change between calls though.

Comment: What im taking the most out of you answer is that I dont know enough and that my Q is in place. can you refer me to a more comprehensive article that explains all the considerations you have raised?